# Android toasts sometimes not showing when the app was started for the first time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toast

I understand that the title might sound a little bit misleading, but it will make sense in a second.

**When does the problem occur?**
The `toasts` are shown always, but not at the first time when the user launches the app. When the app is fired for the first time an App Intro is being displayed, In my `MainActivity` i check my `SharedPreferences`and start an `Intent` which holds the `AppIntro` when the user visits the app the first time.

I show a quick Intro and also ask the User for the `Storage Permission` Then my `SearchFragment` in the corresponding `ViewPager` is shown.

**When and where are the Toasts being fired?**
When the user clicks on a Button, I call the method `showInfoToast()` where I pass the `Context` and the `String` as Argument and then my Toasts are being shown. I use the Library `Toasty` from GrenderG but it doesn't make any difference with the default Toast.

```
public static void showInfoToast(String infoMessage, Context context) {
    Toasty.info(context, infoMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
}
```

**What have I tried / what do I think the problem is?**

- The Context passed to the method. As said I call the method showInfoToast in my `onClickListener` in the `SearchFragment` I pass `getContext()` But it seems not to be the problem, as I have seen when I stepped over it with the Debugger, Context is from the MainActivity.
- The Library Toasty but the same error occures in the default Toasts

> That's why in my opinion somehow the App Intro Intent messes up the Context/The SearchFragment the problem has to be there as it only happens on the first launch of the app.

**Code snippet onClickListener in Search Fragment:**

```
goViralButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            synchronized (this) {
                 showInfoToast("Please add users", getContext());
            }
        }
    });
```

**Code snippet App Intro launched by the MainActivity:**

```
//  Initialize SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    //  Create a new boolean and preference and set it to true
    boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

    //  If the activity has never started before...
    if (isFirstStart) {

        //  Launch app intro
        final Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        //  Make a new preferences editor
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();

        //  Edit preference to make it false because we don't want this to run again
        e.putBoolean("firstStart", false);

        //  Apply changes
        e.apply();
    }
```

**Logcat output when I press the goViral Button:**

```
Unable to start animation, surface is null or no children.
Toast already killed
...
```

Comment: I think this is not in your Toast issue. It can be happened for SharedPreference default value.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem as the Intro (The intent) gets closed after showing the Tutorial, then the user can click on the UI of the SearchFragment

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint where the OnClickListener is being set to confirm that it is executing when the user launches the app for the first time?

Comment: Your logcat is not related to your problem so somehow your preference can be saved . Have a look again.

Comment: @bartonstanley yes it's executing but also If I debugged no toast has been shown. I checked the Context which is passed to the Toast and it's from the MainActivity